# Undefined array key "permissions" error after upgrade to Craft4

Tags: craft3, craft4, upgrades

Hi need some help here.
I recently I tried to upgrade Craftcms from Craft Pro 3.7.55.2 to Craft Pro 4.3.6.1, there is no error in migration, but when I try to edit a user group, I got this error:

```
[web.ERROR] [yii\base\ErrorException:2] Undefined array key "permissions" {"trace":["#0 /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/ErrorHandler.php(79): yii\\base\\ErrorHandler->handleError()","#1 /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/UserPermissions.php(759): craft\\web\\ErrorHandler->handleError()","#2 /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/UserPermissions.php(210): craft\\services\\UserPermissions->_filterOrphanedPermissions()","#3 /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/UserSettingsController.php(100): craft\\services\\UserPermissions->saveGroupPermissions()","#4 [internal function]: craft\\controllers\\UserSettingsController->actionSaveGroup()","#5 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array()","#6 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(178): yii\\base\\InlineAction->runWithParams()","#7 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(552): yii\\base\\Controller->runAction()","#8 /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(301): yii\\base\\Module->runAction()","#9 /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(625): craft\\web\\Application->runAction()","#10 /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(280): craft\\web\\Application->_processActionRequest()","#11 /app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): craft\\web\\Application->handleRequest()","#12 /app/web/index.php(84): yii\\base\\Application->run()","#13 {main}"],"memory":18537592,"exception":"[object] (yii\\base\\ErrorException(code: 2): Undefined array key \"permissions\" at /app/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/UserPermissions.php:759)"}
```

Any idea? thanks

Edited:

I output all the groups here https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/services/UserPermissions.php#L759, looks it's related to another plugin Migration Assistant, no 'permissions' there

```
'Migration Assistant' => [
    'createContentMigrations' => [
        'label' => 'Create content migrations'
    ]
]
18 => [
    'heading' => 'Navigation'
    'permissions' => [
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks plugin Migration Assistant won't support craftcms 4
https://github.com/dgrigg/craft-migration-assistant/issues/51